# Exchange-traded security that represents the value of a government bond?

Tags: bonds, stock-exchanges

Is there an exchange-traded security that represents the value of a government bond? Since the latter have a very large volume, I would be interested to see to what extent private investors can benefit from the rising demand for government bonds.

Specifically, I am interested in government bonds from stable or large economies such as the US or large European countries.

Comment: Why not buy the bond itself?

Comment: The price is too high. As far as I know, government bonds are placed in a price range from millions or billions on.

Comment: @Kutsubato No, they have a par value of $1,000, but you can buy fractional amounts in increments of $100. They sell millions of them at one time, though. Also remember that there are several "types" of bonds that differ in maturity. You can buy them directly through [Treasury Direct](https://www.treasurydirect.gov)

Comment: But when I want to increase diversity, it is probably still better to invest into ETFs holding multiple government bonds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://etfdb.com/etfdb-category/government-bonds/

You can find many here.

Also pay attention to duration, they affect how sensitive the fund is to interest rate change (and how volatile the fund is).